# Help with MySQL Procedure Nested IF ELSE statments

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, if-statement

Hi I need help with nested if else statements in MySQL. **Please verify if the code below are the same**? The C code is what I want to be accomplished in MySQL. I don't have syntax errors. But it seems that I am not getting the right result.

**MySQL Stored Proc**

```
IF top10_rank <= 10 AND top100_rank <=10 THEN SET temp_rank = 10;
ELSE SET temp_rank = 100;
END IF;


IF temp_rank = 10 THEN
  IF top10_rank_date > top100_rank_date THEN SET rank = top10_rank;
  ELSE SET rank = top100_rank;
  END IF;
ELSEIF temp_rank = 100 THEN SET rank = top100_rank;
ELSE SET rank = 0;
END IF;
```

**C code**

```
if(top10_rank <= 10 && top100_rank <=10)
{
    temp_rank = 10;
}
else
{
    temp_rank = 100;
}

if(temp_rank == 10)
{
    if(top10_rank_date > top100_rank_date)
    {
        rank = top10_rank
    }
    else
    {
        rank = top100_rank
    }
}
else if(temp_rank == 100)
{
    rank = top100_rank;
}
else
{
    rank = 0;
}
```

Comment: What differences occur? When you input something in the C code and the same in the MySQL code when does the output differ?

Comment: I don't know exactly, I just don't know how to debug stored procedure code. But I don't get what I expect to happen on my stored procedure so I'm guessing it's this part. But if the code above are the same, then I'm looking at the wrong part of the code.

Comment: Why in the world are you trying to write procedural code like that in a stored proc?? Write it in C where it belongs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the pieces are equivalent without regarding such things as size of integer (? may be float) fields and handling of NULL values in SQL.
Code looks not good:

1) This code is unreachable:

```
else
{
    rank = 0;
}
```

2) It could be shortened - temp_rank could be inlined

3) Probably you need use this function is SELECT, it could be rewritten with CASE operator - to make calls more effective

4) To detect a problem, wrap the C and SQL pieces in functions and specify for which input parameters results are different.